# python dictionary key Vs object attribute

Tags: python, dictionary, object

suppose i have object has key 'dlist0' with attribute 'row_id'  the i can access as

```
getattr(dlist0,'row_id')
```

then it return value
but if i have a dictionary

```
ddict0 = {'row_id':4, 'name':'account_balance'}
getattr(ddict0,'row_id')
```

it is not work

my question is how can i access ddict0 and dlist0 same way

any one can help me?

Comment: :) yes i have got ... '__getitem__' property can be use for both of them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionaries have items, and thus use whatever is defined as `__getitem__()` to retrieve the value of a key.

Objects have attributes, and thus use `__getattr__()` to retrieve the value of an attribute.

You can theoretically override one to point at the other, if you need to - but why do you need to? Why not just write a helper function instead:

Python 2.x:

```
def get_value(some_thing, some_key):
    if type(some_thing) in ('dict','tuple','list'):
        return some_thing[some_key]
    else:
        return getattr(some_thing, some_key)
```

Python 3.x:

```
def get_value(some_thing, some_key):
    if type(some_thing) in (dict,tuple,list):
        return some_thing[some_key]
    else:
        return getattr(some_thing, some_key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) is more suitable for your purpose

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> AccountBalance=namedtuple('account_balance','row_id name')
>>> ddict0=AccountBalance(**{'row_id':4, 'name':'account_balance'})
>>> getattr(ddict0,'row_id')
4

>>> ddict0._asdict()
{'row_id': 4, 'name': 'account_balance'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although similar to [@Amber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279025), the following is slightly more concise, and allows us to specify a default value. Gets either a `dict` item or an `object` attribute:

```py
def get(*args):
    _get = dict.get if type(args[0]) is dict else getattr
    return _get(*args)
```

The arguments for [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) are similar. Both accept an optional default value. Note, however, that `getattr` raises an error if the attribute does not exist and default is not explicitly specified.

Some trivial examples:

```py
>>> get({'my_key': 'my_value'}, 'my_key')
'my_value'
```

```py
>>> class MyClass(object): pass
...
>>> get(MyClass(), 'my_attr_name', 'missing')
'missing'
```